# How to figure out for which original call onCharacteristicChanged was triggered?

Tags: java, bluetooth-lowenergy, characteristics

I have device that accepts commands in write characteristic and returns back data in notification characteristic. Problem is when I call 2 different commands (call 2 writes) and notifications returned back to me all mixed up I need to know for which write call this notification is for.

Q: is there way to find that out? Like call to write returns some id and its included into notification?

Comment: Do you also write the firmware for the BLE device yourself?

Comment: Unfortunatly I dont. I wish :)

Comment: Can't you just write one command, wait for the notification and write the second command afterward?

Comment: I can but it would complicate my code. Was hoping to find cleaner solution

Comment: There is no standard for what you want to do. If you can't reprogram the peripheral you need to do it one after another

Comment: When I looked at wireshark I can see that they spot which reply was for which request (not all but some) so I was hoping that there is something hidden in the reply data that im not aware of

Comment: I'm not aware of something like this, sorry